# Highlight the text in image using tesseract.js

Tags: javascript, tesseract.js

I came across this awesome feature in [mobbin.com](https://mobbin.com/) which highlights the given text in the image. I guess they are using Tesseract.js (Not sure).

[Here is their changelog (If it's relevant)](https://mobbin.com/changelog/2023-07-27-text-search-highlights)

[image]

I'm sure they are using RadixUI, TailwindCSS. But not sure about the part how the highlight is done.

It's kind of overlay above the text.

```
<div class="relative overflow-hidden bg-bg-secondary after:absolute after:inset-0 after:rounded-[--border-radius] after:shadow-image-inset" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px; --border-radius: 30.869999999999997px; border-radius: 30.87px;">

<img crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://upcdn.io/FW25bBB/image/content/app_screens/e8d025b3-982a-45c6-b8c6-946fef3446f9.png?f=webp&amp;w=1920&amp;q=85&amp;fit=shrink-cover&amp;extend-bottom=120&amp;image=%2Fwatermark%2Fff806217-a840-497f-a23e-90760ae3aa1e&amp;gravity=bottom" alt="Vivid screen" class="h-full w-full object-cover object-top">

<span class="absolute bg-[#FFE500]/30 shadow rounded-4" style="inset: 36.5023% 56.9975% 60.7199% 29.3469%;"></span>

<span class="absolute bg-[#FFE500]/30 shadow rounded-4" style="inset: 36.5023% 38.3376% 60.4069% 41.2214%;"></span>

</div>
```

Those span tags is setting the yellow highlight.

Any Idea how this can be done in React or Nextjs.